# Sveltekit adapter-static fails: Cannot read property 'kit' of undefined

Tags: sveltekit

I'm trying to build a Sveltekit site using the `adapter-static`.
`npm run preview` works fine and `npm run build` seems to build fine before giving me a cryptic error:

`Cannot read property 'kit' of undefined`.

Can you point me towards a way to debug this - I cannot find where exactly the issue is.

Comment: Can you show the whole stack trace?

Comment: I have this problem as well and haven't been able to find a solution

Comment: @Catalactics This is what I get: ```> Cannot read property 'kit' of undefined
    at adapt (file:///Users/alfred/Documents/Projects/studion22/node_modules/@sveltejs/adapter-static/index.js:15:37)
    at adapt (file:///Users/alfred/Documents/Projects/studion22/node_modules/@sveltejs/kit/dist/chunks/index5.js:740:8)
    at file:///Users/alfred/Documents/Projects/studion22/node_modules/@sveltejs/kit/dist/cli.js:994:11```

Comment: @Alfred, can you show us your `svelte.config.js`? The `kit` sounds like your config might be broken somehow

Comment: @Catalactics Thanks for the help, it looks like this: ```import adapter from '@sveltejs/adapter-static'

const config = {
 kit: {
  target: '#svelte',
  adapter: adapter()
 }
}

export default config```

Comment: Your config seems correct, I'm sorry if I'm asking a lot, but can you possibly give a link to the project

Comment: @Catalactics I think that Sveltekit and adapter-static were out of sync. Created a new project and now it works.

Answer (score 1):

Svelte is still under active development. Most likely you're trying to use the latest documentation while having the older Svelte dependencies installed locally.

Upgrading your Svelte dependencies should solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try to create a new project with a fresh install of `SvelteKit` and `adapter-static` and then copy your code from the old project. That worked for me. Seems like the two were out of sync.